# Value change upon assigning data from array to range

Tags: vba, array

I'm writing back my data from an array to range.

The variables stored in array are of Variant/String type:

```
20.00
20.99
etc.
```

But when they are put into range (formatted as General), the values are:

```
20,00
20,99
etc.
```

Dot is replaced with comma.

I cannot format target cells beforehand to text, because in some of them there's a formula.
How to escape this problem?

Comment: Comma is a decimal separator in some locales. Please check your system's region settings.

Comment: It sure is. Changing the decimal symbol made a change. But I cannot use this solution, as the numbers mentioned above are not numbers to me, but rather codes. I'd like to keep my decimal symbol (comma), and have my codes treated literally, not as numbers. Is there a kill switch in Excel that prevents the app recognizing the data type?

Comment: You don't want do format the target cells beforehand, but you can do it just before writing the data into the range (as you are going to replace any formulas anyway). Use `rng.NumberFormat="@"`. Also, you will need to ensure that your Array contains Strings, so Dim it that way and fill it with strings, not with numbers. (If that is not possible, you will have to Format and Replace your values to make them into strings)

Comment: `rng.NumberFormat="@"` will format my target as text. I cannot do that as I'm writing back values and formulas. With range formatted as text, my formulas won't work. I will not replace any formulas because my range is set to General format and I'm using `arr = rng.Formula2` to load array (formulas are preserved).

Comment: @Rayearth you may want to add that information to the question, it wasn't quite clear and you example only had numeric values. In order to solve your problem, you will need to establish within you vba code whether you are writing back a value or a formula, as they will have to be treated differently